# HTTP Post from Android to Wampserver - Client denied by server configuration

Tags: android, apache, http-post, wampserver

I implemented an HTTP Post from my Android application to Wampserver a while ago, tested it at the time and it worked perfectly. I've come back to it because I've integrated into another application and it doesn't seem to be working anymore. Maybe it's to do with my Wampserver configuration?

I checked my Apache error log and I don't quite understand what this means:

```
Fri Mar 16 20:49:28 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.25] client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/android/base.php
```

Comment: You need to check apache config, especially directives "Allow" and "Deny" for this virtual host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Apache `httpd.conf` is configured so it denies access from that host (or probably all hosts).

Probably there is a `<Directory>` entry in there that has `Deny from all` in it (this is the new default in Apache 2.2). Comment that out and it should work.

Comment: Just the 'Deny from all' line?

Comment: Yes, try commenting only that first.

Comment: Or try adding `Allow from all`